# AC Air Intake Compartment - Is Repairing This a Reality?

Tags: air-conditioning, central-air

I moved into a 425 sq ft apartment about a month ago. The AC had a leak for awhile. When I found it, they replaced the AC. I have had the new AC for about 2 weeks.

I have a musky old wood odor in my apartment that is real strong. I believe it is because the air intake compartment is not sealed. For instance, today was a real windy and I could feel and smell super hot musky air gathering in the air conditioner closet.

Would it be unreasonable to ask the landlord to repair the air intake compartment so it is sealed and the interior wall air does not get sucked in? I'm not a carpenter, but it looks like it would be very difficult to get to the compartment to repair it.

In the photos, I sealed it up so I would not smell the old foul wood odor. I just live with the AC off and windows open all the time now.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Tried following your nose to the source of said odor?

Comment: I believe it is the source. Because when I unsealed it and opened it, that odor was strong in there. Along with hot outside air collected in there....heated like it came from a  blow drier(it was windy today in Texas and 87 degrees).

Comment: What is all that matter all over the place, on the walls, on the floor?  Is that going to make the stuff go away?

Comment: Some kind of cement. The baking soda was my feeble attempt as a non carpenter and tenant to handle the odor(which didn't do a thing).

Comment: Is that space some sort of joist cavity by chance? I'm wondering if there's a much bigger problem here than you're seeing

Comment: I'm not sure. It's not a air intake without metal sheeting. Is this considered a joist cavity?